# eas build java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

Tags: firebase, react-native, build, expo

I am having an issue achieving a successful buld due to two errors.  I have no idea how to fix these errors... anyone have an Idea on what to try to correct these errors?

[Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTysy.png)

Comment: yes I am having the same issue running eas build

Comment: Me too, no idea what causes the problem